# eclipse plugin code to create IProject in specified location

Tags: eclipse-plugin

```
IProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new NullProgressMonitor();

IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IProject project = root.getProject(page1.getProjectName());
```

I am using this code to create a project in workspace.

Now I want to create a project in a specified location other than workspace.

Can anyone give some suggestions?

Comment: I'm unsure if it helps, but what is you programming language? Java? to topic itself I have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the code to specify the location of the project to be created.
This can be done by using the setLocation() method of IProjectDescription class as follows:

```
IProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();


IProject project = root.getProject(page1.getProjectName());
    IWorkspace w = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IProjectDescription desc=w.newProjectDescription(project.getName()); 
    String projectLocation=page1.getProjectLocation();
    IPath path1=new Path(projectLocation+"/"+page1.getProjectName());
    desc.setLocation(path1); 
    project.create(desc, progressMonitor); 
    project.open(progressMonitor);
```

Comment: You should probably check  -  if (!wizardPage.useDefaults()) {
   IPath path1 = new Path(projectLocation + "/" + wizardPage.getProjectName());
   desc.setLocation(path1);
  }