# How to create a new Java project in a particular location programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I need to create a new java project pro-grammatically.
I have done this using the following:

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(projectName);
```

How can I create this project in a location other than my work-space?
I have a string which gives me the location where I need to create this project.

Comment: Which IDE do you use, Eclipse?

Comment: Yes I'm using eclipse

Comment: I got my answer here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382368/eclipse-plugin-code-to-create-iproject-in-specified-location>